# Storing a string of words in a data structure

Tags: c, data-structures

I want to create a program which receives some input words from the user, stores the inputs in a data structure and then prints the data structure on a txt file.

Right now i only built the part where it receives some inputs and stores them in a data structure, and then i added a printf to print the data structure, just for testing.

The problem is, if i input "test_one" on char "one" it will print "test_one", but if i input "test one", it will only print "test". 
How can i edit it so that it stores entire words instead of only one? Can i do that with pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct inputs {
   char one[30];
   char two[30];
   char three[30];     
};

int main(void)
{  

   struct inputs inputs = {"", "", ""};
   scanf("%s%s%s", inputs.one, inputs.two, inputs.three);

   printf("\n%s;%s;%s\n", inputs.one, inputs.two, inputs.three);


   } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I only knew about gets, not fgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scanf with the standard "%s" will only read the input until it reaches a whitespace. Try this to read until a new line:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", inputs.one);
scanf("%[^\n]s", inputs.two);
scanf("%[^\n]s", inputs.three);
```

Comment: One question: why does it only take one input? It only runs the first scanf and will ignore the other two